# Obtaining Slack trigger_id from slash command

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-dialog

I'm looking to open a dialog in Slack based on the user executing a basic slash command. I can currently capture the payload from a slash command in my API, and action this accordingly, but my understanding is that in order to open a dialog I need a corresponding `trigger_id`, which doesn't seem to be present in the payload.

The only values I have are: `token`, `channel_name`, `user_name`, `command` and `text`.

I might be misunderstanding this, but everything I have read seems to suggest that I *should* have said `trigger_id` as part of my incoming payload. Is this correct?

I do have Interactivity turned on within my app, but can't see anything in there to link this to a slash command. Is that a correct assumption that they are separate? Or are they linked in some way?

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: Yes, the payload should have `trigger_id`. Without revealing any sensitive information, could you post the payload you're receiving?

Comment: This wasn't a slack issue, but a C# issue my side. The `trigger_id` was being received within the payload but not serialised properly on the server as the object was specified as `TriggerId` on the object.

For anyone having this problem in C#, just ensure the trigger ID column is defined as `trigger_id`

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't a slack issue, but a C#/serialisation issue my side. The `trigger_id` *was* being received within the payload, but not serialised properly on the server (even though a `JsonProperty` was defined), as the object was specified as `TriggerId` on the object itself. For anyone having this problem in C#, just ensure the trigger ID column is defined as `trigger_id`